# PhpStorm and projects with remote files, keeping environments mirrored

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm for a while now but I'm a bit confused for the right way to work on projects with remote files.

At the moment I've created a project (FTP) and download everything from the deployment server. When I save a file it gets uploaded automatically but there are situations where I'm working from another device using a different approach to modify files.

At this moment I'm redownloading the entire deployment server, but this seems like an overkill. Is there a method like 'sync' to just download/modify the remote changed files? I know there is an item in the context menu 'Synchronize "Project name"', but this doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: **First of all:** *"I know there is an item in the context menu 'Synchronize "Project name"'"* Where? What screen/tool window is that? Does it has the same icon as "File | Synchronize" ? If so -- then it's not what you think -- it only reloads local files looking for changes made outside of IDE.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question so I'll add it as a comment but you probably want to look into a VCS such as git rather than relying on FTP... that way you can issue git pull and it will download all the changes (and only changes) then git push and it will upload any changes you've made (all of them, and only the changes)

Comment: Further to Tom B's answer; [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) will allow you to do all your development in Git (and thus work easily on more than one machine) but only push the updated files to an ordinary FTP server.